# "python" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo

Tags: python, python-2.7, consola, sublimetext3, windows7

Estoy aprendiendo python, lo estoy ejecutando en Sublime Text 3 y tengo w7, cuando ejecuto algo para que lo muestre en consola, aparece este mensaje:

> "python" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

ya agregué la ruta en el path y sigue igual

¿como puedo solucionarlo?, ya he intentado varias cosas y no encuentro solución.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que editar las variables de entorno http://www.scielo.org.mx/avaliacao/manual_marcacion/instalacion_markup_paths.html
para que reconozca la ruta donde se instaló python.

Comment: Además para trabajar con python te recomiendo el IDE pycharm

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Hola Julian, sería ideal que incluyeras las partes clave de la página enlazada porque si el enlace se rompe y deja de funcionar, la respuesta perderá sentido. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más recomendaciones (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).